# Can't set cookie from remote server to localhost react.js application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies

I have a problem with React and NodeJS. What is happening is that I'm working with cookies to authenticate a Login, for that, when I have my backend running in localhost on my machine with the React App, in the chrome settings I can see the cookie (application --> cookies), but, when I deploy the backend on a server (doesn't have ssl, it's only http and has its own domain), The cookie is not being setted, but for some reason when I try to do the HTTP Request in postman to server, It gives me the Cookie. So I have the question....how can I get the cookie from my local React app running on my PC while my backend is running on a dev server.

PD: I have read on google, and my React app is requesting with axios and I put {withCredentials:true}, in my node.js app I have configured the cors settings as { origin: true, credentials: true}.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Share your code please otherwise we can't tell you what to do